# emacs: have path be a part of buffer name instead of `<2>`

Tags: emacs

I'm working on a golang project, where there are a lot of files with the same name, in different directories.

For example, there's a *parser* class, and a *handler* class, both of which have separate directories, but the filenames in the two directories are nearly identical.

Is there a way to tell emacs to show path as buffer name prefix, instead of affixing `<2>` to the repeating buffer names as a suffix?

Answer (score 5):

See the Emacs manual, node `Uniquify`, and user option `uniquify-buffer-name-style`.

```
C-h r g uniquify RET
```

You can customize the option value to `forward` to get the behavior you request.

In Emacs versions older than Emacs 23 you will not find node `Uniquify` in the manual, and you will need to explicitly require library `uniquify.el` in your init file (`~/.emacs`):

```
(require 'uniquify)
```

Comment: I get `Info file emacs does not exist` as soon as I `C-h r`.

Comment: Did you install the Emacs documentation?  Some distributions (notably, Debian and derivates thereof) do not include the documentation in the Emacs packages, for licensing reasons.

Comment: @lunaryorn, yes, I've been trying the above on Debian.  So, I need to install a documentation package, in order to use the feature?  Strange way of doing things...

Comment: @cnst Er, no, obviously.  The answer tells you what option to customize.  The manual will tell you how uniquify (and Emacs in general) works, but is not required to actually use it, of course.  I just replied to your comment.

Comment: @lunaryorn, but I'm following the answer -- i'm getting the message as above when trying to do exactly what the answer says i should do.  do i just ignore the message, and continue the command as is?

Comment: The `C-h r ...` command just accesses the documentation.  You don't need to do that to configure or enable uniquify.  Also, you can get the docs on the web, google works to search it: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Uniquify.html